# Why don't I get an error in my assembly code below in VS2017, when I suppress the definition for the entry point as shown below?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86

The code below compiles and links without an error message even when the entry point (`main`) is not defined for the linker in VS2017, as can be seen in this [printscreen](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtUORDHG8Blgjmd-5hBxtcynQN1j) in my one drive.

```
.386
.MODEL flat, stdcall
.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO STDCALL, dwExitCode: DWORD 


.DATA

.DATA?

.CODE
main PROC
    mov eax, 16

    invoke ExitProcess, 0

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: The linker is informed through the `END main` statement that the entry point is the `main` symbol.  The `main` symbol is defined by the `main PROC` statement.  So `main` is both defined and linker knows that the its supposed to be the entry point.  I don't see how you've tried to "suppress" any of this.

Comment: @RossRidge You seem to be right. If I suppress the name `main` from the statement  `END main` I get the linker error `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup` which is what I was expecting for the code above. Thanks.